# How do I start my android emulator with go?

Tags: android, go, command

I am trying to write my first go program that starts a android emulator without starting Android studio and the avd manager.

I wrote a bat file first

```
c:
cd C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
start /min "Android Emulator" emulator.exe -avd Pixel_3a_API_30
```

Which works but I want the terminal to be hidden instead of minimized. So since I want to experiment with GO I tried running the command with go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command(`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe`, "-avd Pixel_3a_API_30")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%v", err)
    }
}
```

This does not give a error but it also does no start the emulator. What am I doing wrong?

This is the output

```
$ go run .
2020/09/05 17:14:02 exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to split the arguments. So "-avd" and "Pixel_3a_API_30" are now seperated

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command(`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe`, "-avd", "Pixel_3a_API_30")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%v", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any exit status not 0 is an error from the shell. That is not equal to a golang error (the command executed, however the command internally threw an error). This is often the case by lack of environment, eg paths etc which are not present in the shell started by golang to execute your command (this goes pretty much for all languages: When you start a command in a shell, make certain it did inherit or initialize an environment).

The common solution then is to provide an environment or make certain that all calls are absolute (which is not really portable outside of your system or a dedicated environment like a docker container).